# Applying cycling colors in Vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm looking at binding several colours to a spinner component, I'm having a bit of trouble doing this at the moment and my brain is getting a little fuzzy.

This is the component itself, bound to a computed value.

```
<fingerprint-spinner :animation-duration="1500" :size="95" :color="this.magicRoundabout" />
```

Here's the computed value

```
        magicRoundabout() {
            let colours = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
            return colours.forEach((item) => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                return item
            }, 1000)
            })

        },
```

I'm looking at having the colors cycle through to create a nice multicolored effect.

Alternatively if there's a way to add a gradient to the "color" property then that would be great! Been having some trouble testing this myself and haven't yielded any fruit from my labour.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use `this` to call your computed variable in view.

I would raise the function in a different way, so that it generates a random number every certain time and that number is the index of the array in your case generates a number between 0 and 1 and this return returns the color directly.

Answer (score 0):

Your are executing 3 `setTimeout`s on the same time because your loop `forEach` will loop through that array in microseconds , so you will get the last color only which is `green` ... this is one way how you can achieve that (run the snippet below) :

```js
Vue.component('coloredComp', {
  props: ['color'],
  template: "<div id='box' :style='{backgroundColor : color}'></div>"
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      color: 'red'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      let colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue']
      let i = 0;
      var int = setInterval(() =>{
        this.color = colors[i];
        i++;
        i == colors.length ? i=0 : '';
      }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
#box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <colored-comp :color="color"></colored-comp>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mtlj1991 nice,if you think the answer is correct or helped you somehow please consider giving an up-vote or validate the answer , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this working thanks to Dadboz!

Is there a way to add a transition into this as well? I've played around with gradients by adding something similar to ''linear-gradient(red, blue)' in the array but wasn't successful.

Looking to achieve a smooth transition between colors as opposed to inducing seizures.